# Python scrapy submitting form data

Tags: scrapy

Good day. So i'm trying to figure out how submitting form data works.

**So this is the form that i want to submit**

[image]

**This is how the network process looks**
[image]

**This is the code**

```
class OutletBot(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'hun73r'
    start_urls = ['https://www.laptopoutlet.co.uk/']
    allowed_domains = ['laptopoutlet.co.uk/']

    def parse(self, response):

        z = response.css('.header-bottom-wrap>div>div>div>form')
        type = ''
        brand = ''
        core = ''
        screensize = ''
        for option in z.css('#brand_div>select>option').extract():
            if 'APPLE' in option:
                brand = option.split('"')[1]
                print(brand)
        for option in z.css('#processor_div>select>option').extract_first():
            if 'i5' in option:
                core = option.split('"')[1]
                print(core)

        formdata = {'type': type,
                    'brand': brand,
                    'core': core,
                    'screensize': screensize}

        yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            clickdata={'type': 'submit'},
            # callback=self.parse_form,
            formdata=formdata,
            method='GET')
```

When i test this code in the terminal for a response, it yields the `/checkout/cart/` form.
How can i get to sumbit the `/categorysearch/advanced/result/` form?
 What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

So i found out that the `from_response` has a argument `formid` which i set to the id of the form

```
formid='search_filter_form',
```